# What is the correct format ofNinjaTrader ATI command?

Tags: ninjatrader

I'm trying to open order ninja trader platform with automated trading interface For that, I have enabled the ati service from options setting in Ninja Trader and trying to send a command to the suggested port through python like below:

```
import socket
def send_ati_command(command):
    try:
        # Connect to NinjaTrader ATI port
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.connect(('localhost', 36973)) 
            s.sendall(command.encode())
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print('Received', repr(data.decode()))
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)

# Example command
command = "PLACE;Account=Sim101;Instrument=NQ 03-24;Action=BUY;Qty=1;OrderType=MARKET;TIF=DAY"
send_ati_command(command)
```

getting response from the server as:

Received **'2\x00'**

Can someone please identify what I am doing wrong here, Also, there is no log being created while sending the command.